# Not able to choose location of the code on the website

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have a question. Not sure how to ask it properly, but i will try..))

So i have a Wordpress website with ads running, some of them anchor ads at the very bottom. I have got a javascript code from one website who i am affiliate with and i put it in the head of the website. This code is just kinda chat box, but connected to that affiliate website. If somebody will ask question in chat bot, it will be redirected to that website.

But the problem is, this chat box interfere with anchor ads on the website. So, when ad showing up, it cover chat box window.

is it posible to put this chat box window a little bit high, above the anchor ads? or can i set any other position of this chat box by my self?

Here is a code in the snippet

Thanks

[view image of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAzQg.jpg)

```html
<div class="ja-gadget-virtual-assistant-subtle cleanslate">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://components.justanswer.com/css/ja-gadget-virtual-assistant-subtle" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://components.justanswer.com/js/ja-gadget-virtual-assistant-config,ja-gadget-virtual-assistant-subtle"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
require("ja-gadget-virtual-assistant-subtle")(
(function() { var scripts = document.querySelectorAll('script[src="https://components.justanswer.com/js/ja-gadget-virtual-assistant-config,ja-gadget-virtual-assistant-subtle"]'); return scripts[scripts.length - 1].parentNode })(),
require("ja-gadget-virtual-assistant-config")({"affiliateId":"ho|10293|1612","profile":"appliance","settings":"default","trackingPixels":{"transition":"https://trk.justanswer.com/aff_c?offer_id=2&aff_id=10293&file_id=1612"}})
).initialize();
})();
</script>
</div><img src="https://trk.justanswer.com/aff_i?offer_id=2&aff_id=10293&file_id=1612" width="0" height="0" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden;" border="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the position of the chat by CSS. Find the chat wrapper or container and then do something like below. This will just move a little higher the chat.

```
#chat-wrapper-id{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
}
```

Maybe the chat plugin CSS we'll interfere. A deeper insight is needed.

Comment: I Already tried this one, but it didn't help
`.ja-gadget-virtual-assistant-subtle cleanslate {
position: absolute;
bottom-margin: 100px;

}`

Comment: I've been told (cause i am not very familiar with this stuff) that position of the chat box getting from javascript or something on the server side from that website. Is this true?

Comment: Hmm you can overwrite it in the brower. Try: `bottom: 50px !important;`

Comment: Well, maybe there's a script that update the position... But it looks like a fix position at the bottom of the window, makes no sense.

Comment: `.ja-gadget-virtual-assistant-subtle cleanslate` is not a valid CSS selector. Are you selecting the correct element?

Comment: Perhaps it's the wrong class/id... inspect the code in chrome and perhaps the provided answers will work with alternative class/id?

Comment: The code located here (https://components.justanswer.com/js/ja-gadget-virtual-assistant-config,ja-gadget-virtual-assistant-subtle) and seems like this `ja-gadget-virtual-assistant-subtle cleanslate` is correct